# Differential Amplifier with Large Capacitive Load

Tags: audio, decoupling-capacitor, differential-amplifier

I am experimenting with the following mixer circuit for audio:

**EDIT: SCHEMATIC FIXED**
[image]

All of the subcircuits work fine separately but when the diff amps are combined with the summer circuit, the large capacitances C3&C4 cause them to go unstable. Placing 47 Ohm resistors at the amp outputs helps, but doesn't entirely solve the issue. I want to use these amps for the high CM input, is there any way around this instability issue? Thanks.

Comment: You have something wired wrong.  There is already at least 1k in seres with C3 and C4.  Why should adding an additional 47 ohms improve things? What frequency is the instability?

Comment: I've read in numerous places that sometimes placing a low value resistor at the output of opamps that don't like capacitive loads and before a large cap can often cure oscillation problems. One example: http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/techniques-to-avoid-instability-capacitive-loading.html  While this article doesn't refer specifically to diff amps and the circuit topology is different, I figured it was worth a shot, and it did make a noticeable difference.

Comment: a resistor is a good way of solving the problem but shouldn't have been necessary in this case unless you have  wiring problem.  The 220uF caps already have a 1k resistor in series (R2,R3)

Answer (score 2):

Where is the supply decoupling?

I find R1,2,3 rather low, are you sure the INA149 can drive into a 1k load satisfactorily, try using 10k here?

The TLE2426 usually likes quite a lot of cap on the output, I have seen these act out if this is missing, try 100uF from its output to ground.

That right hand opamp looks like it is trying to be a MFB filter but is actually wired with its inverting and non inverting inputs reversed, that is not going to work.

What does your ground layout look like? when you close those switches the '149s are having to source quite some audio current, and if that disturbs the ground for the TLE2426.

Comment: I was going say the last filter opamp is wrong.. but you found many more  potential problems.

Comment: In my haste to get this posted I made a few mistakes in the schematic (backwards sallen-key amp, left off the decoupling). The new schematic shows how it's actually wired, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

After doing extensive testing, it turns out that the actual problem was not the diff amp driving the high capacitance. I'm using MAX4622 analog CMOS/TTL switches, wired as shown:

[image]

I'm using a pushbutton for testing, and it seems if my finger is in contact with either of the metal contacts, then the signal response at the output is as expected. However, if I do NOT touch either of the contacts, the output signal shown on the scope starts drifting around (DC bias) and the sine wave starts fluttering (for lack of better term), changing shape rapidly.

Replacing the analog switch with the pushbutton switch, everything functions as expected, so it seems the issue has nothing to do with the diff amp. Not sure if it's possible to comment on answers, but any continued comments explaining this phenomenon would be welcome.